# Difference between DrawableCompat and Drawable

Tags: android, android-appcompat

A couple of days ago the support library version **v22.1.0** was released and among the new things I have seen DrawableCompat.

Now my question is what is the difference between DrawableCompat and a normal Drawable, what benefits does it bring and when and how to use it.

I have read [Chris Banes' blog](https://chris.banes.me/2015/04/22/support-libraries-v22-1-0/), but it is lacking to properly explain what this is and how it could be useful for developers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quoting the blog post in question:

> The Drawable tinting methods added in Lollipop are super useful for letting you dynamically tint assets.

Here, tinting refers to the `Theme.Material`/`Theme.AppCompat` approach of using grayscale drawables and applying tints, like `colorPrimary` or `colorAccent`, to tie them into a custom theme for an app. This is used in lots of places, in particular many places where the accent color is seen.

Continuing with the blog post:

> AppCompat had its own baked in implementation in the v21 support library and we’ve now extracted that into DrawableCompat in support-v4 for everyone to use.

Hence, `DrawableCompat` allows you to use the tint-the-grayscale image as `appcompat-v7` does, for tinting drawables, going back to API Level 4. This is in contrast to the similar tinting methods available on `Drawable` starting with API Level 21. In particular, if you are creating custom widgets *and* using `appcompat-v7`, you might use `DrawableCompat` to allow your widgets to adopt the app's color scheme.

> what is the difference between DrawableCompat and a normal Drawable

`DrawableCompat` departs from the typical `...Compat` approach. Classes like `NotificationCompat.Builder` are replacements for their progenitors (e.g., `Notification.Builder`). In this case, `DrawableCompat` applies certain changes, like the tint, to another `Drawable`, where that other drawable is "wrapped" by `DrawableCompat`. `DrawableCompat` simply provides the API and the wrap/unwrap capabilities; it is the `Drawable` that you get from `wrap()` that you would use in your app, in lieu of using the original grayscale `Drawable` that you started with.